# I would like to know how i can add a logo to an header with just html and css

Tags: html, css

I understand that adding the image to the header is an HTML feature but I don't know how to go about it. Below is my HTML code. I am a beginner and this would be my first project any form of help is really appreciated.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
     <title> Mike Flora </title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href ="style.css">
<head>
<body>

<div class="fixed-header">
<h1>Welcome to Mike Flora</h1>
<div class="container">
    <nav>
    <a href="sofar.html">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
     <a href="#">Products</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
       <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
       
        </nav>
        </div>
        </div>

<h6>Register Here</h6>
    <div><input type="text" placeholder = "First Name" name = "name">
    </div>
    <div><input type= "Password" placeholder="Password" name= "Password">
    </div>
    <div><input type= "text" placeholder= "Local Government" name= "Local Government">
    </div>
    <button>Submit</button>
    <h2>Words from the HeadMaster</h2>
    <br>We are glad you found us. We hope you find that which you seek here</br>
    

<div class="container">
<div class="fixed-footer">
    
    <div class="container">Copyright &copy; 2016 Your Company</div>     

    
</div>
    

    
    
</body>
```

Comment: background-image and some padding?

Comment: Are you looking for the [img](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) tag?

Answer (score 0):

Glad to hear you're starting something new. I think to solve you're problem you can use the img tag. It would look something like this:

```
<nav>
    <a href="sofar.html">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Products</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    <img src="path/to/your/image.png" width='50px' height='50px'>
</nav>
```

If you wanted it to link somewhere you could wrap it in 'a' tags as well.

```
<a href="sofar.html"><img src="path/to/your/image.png" width='50px' height='50px'></a>
```

Hopefully this works for you. Oh and you can change the height and width to be whatever you want obviously.

Good luck!

Edit: Just so you know you will have to have the image/logo that you are trying to display in you're source folder, and then will link to it in the src of the img tag.

If you're confused about that this should help:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp